# Write message to file in camel ?

Tags: java, apache-camel

I want to get message from(amq) and write to(some file). I able to get message from AMQ but couldn't create file. Please tell me where is a problem here is my route.

```
from("test-jms:queue:Test-AMQ").to("file:test?doneFileName=${file:name}.done");
```

Comment: What doesn't work? What error do you get?

Comment: nothing - it doesn't create file. it just create directory every time when i compile it.

Comment: tested it, works like a charm. Are you putting messages to your queue?

Comment: yes - Nothing wrong with the queue, it not creating .txt file in target directory.

Comment: Can you enable trace (or debug) logging and post it? It's hard to guess and there is nothing wrong with your route above.

Answer (score 2):

see this unit test for a working example:

https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/camel/trunk/components/camel-jms/src/test/java/org/apache/camel/component/jms/JmsRouteToFileTest.java